# How to work with Git branches and Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git

I am working on a rails app with quite a few git branches and many of them include db migrations. We try to be careful but occasionally some piece of code in master asks for a column that got removed/renamed in another branch.

1. **What would be a nice solution to "couple" git branches with DB states?**
2. **What would these "states" actually be?**

   We can't just duplicate a database if it's a few GBs in size.
3. **And what should happen with merges?**
4. **Would the solution translate to noSQL databases as well?**

   We currently use MySQL, mongodb and redis

---

EDIT: Looks like I forgot to mention a very important point, I am only interested in the **development environment** but with large databases (a few GBs in size).

Comment: What are you doing that you have an environment running your master branch whose database can be modified by other branches? I don't understand what your workflow is or why you think you need to keep branches in sync with particular databases.

Comment: Let's say we have a table in our database with clients (name, email, phone) and in a branch we split one of the columns (name -> first_name + last_name). Until we merge the branch with the master, the master and all other branches based on it will fail.

Answer (score 70):

When you add a new migration in any branch, run `rake db:migrate` and commit both the migration **and** `db/schema.rb`

If you do this, in development, you'll be able to switch to another branch that has a different set of migrations and simply run `rake db:schema:load`.

Note that this will **recreate the entire database, and existing data will be lost**.

You'll probably only want to run production off of one branch which you're very careful with, so these steps don't apply there (just run `rake db:migrate` as usual there).  But in development, it should be no big deal to recreate the database from the schema, which is what `rake db:schema:load` will do.

Comment: I think this will only solve the schema problem, the data will be lost with every down migration never to be seen again. Would it be a good idea to save some kind of db-data-patch that gets saved when moving out of a branch and another one that gets loaded when moving into another branch? The patches should only contain the data that would be lost on the way down (migrations).

Comment: If you want to load data, use `db/seeds.rb`  It shouldn't be too devastating to nuke your development DB if you setup some reasonable seed data there.

Comment: no need to nuke anything. see my solution below. Just be aware that you will have many instances and when you switch branches, the data is not there. This is totally fine if you are developing with tests.

Comment: Thank you Andy, this answer also my question.
And agree on using `db/seeds.rb` for ripopulating the lost db data

Comment: For big complicated apps where you need to reproduce real life bugs locally, it's absolutely impossible to use a seeds file, you need the real data from production (or staging). And restoring a database can take quite a while, so no this isn't a good solution for my case.

Answer (score 24):

If you have a large database that you can't readily reproduce, then I'd recommend using the normal migration tools.  If you want a simple process, this is what I'd recommend:

- Before switching branches, rollback (`rake db:rollback`) to the state before the branch point. Then, after switching branches, run `db:migrate`. This is mathematically correct, and as long as  you write `down` scripts, it will work.
- If you forget to do this before switching branches, in general you can safely switch back, rollback, and switch again, so I think as a workflow, it's feasible.
- If you have dependencies between migrations in different branches... well, you'll have to think hard.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that not all migrations are reversible, that said, the first suggested step is not guaranteed to succeed. I think that at development environment a good idea would be to use `rake db:schema:load` and `rake db:seed` as @noodl had said.

Comment: @pisaruk I know you answered this six years ago, but reading I'm curious what an example of a non-reversible migration would be.  I'm having a hard time imagining a situation.  I guess the simplest would be a dropped column containing a bunch of data, but this could be "reversed" to have an empty column or a column with some default value.  Were you thinking of other cases?

Comment: I think you answered your own question! Yes, a dropped column is a good example. Or a destructive data migration.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a script I wrote for switching between branches that contain different migrations:

https://gist.github.com/4076864

It won't solve all the problems you mentioned, but given a branch name it will:

1. Roll back any migrations on your current branch which do not exist on the given branch
2. Discard any changes to the db/schema.rb file
3. Check out the given branch
4. Run any new migrations existing in the given branch
5. Update your test database

I find myself manually doing this all the time on our project, so I thought it'd be nice to automate the process.

Comment: This script does exactly what I want to do, I'd love to see it put into an automatic checkout hook.

Comment: This just in, I forked your gist and made it a post-checkout hook: https://gist.github.com/brysgo/9980344

Comment: In your script, did you really mean to say `git checkout db/schema.rb` or did you mean `git checkout -- db/schema.rb`? (i.e. with double dashes)

Comment: Well yeah... I didn't know about double-dashes at the time. But the command will work the same unless you've got a branch called `db/schema.rb`. :)

Comment: @brysgo's evolved git_rails command (https://github.com/brysgo/git-rails) works great. Thanks to you Jon :)

Comment: Looking through the forks of that gist, I found an excellent rake task https://gist.github.com/sunny/4731403

Answer (score 8):

## Separate Database for each Branch

It's the only way to fly.

#### Update October 16th, 2017

I returned to this after quite some time and made some improvements:

- I've added another namespace rake task to create a branch and clone the database in one fell swoop, with `bundle exec rake git:branch`.
- I realize now that cloning from master is not always what you want to do so I made it more explicit that the `db:clone_from_branch` task takes a `SOURCE_BRANCH` and a `TARGET_BRANCH` environment variable. When using `git:branch` it will automatically use the current branch as the `SOURCE_BRANCH`.
- Refactoring and simplification.

### `config/database.yml`

And to make it easier on you, here's how you update your `database.yml` file to dynamically determine the database name based on the current branch.

```
<% 
database_prefix = 'your_app_name'
environments    = %W( development test ) 
current_branch  = `git status | head -1`.to_s.gsub('On branch ','').chomp
%>

defaults: &defaults
  pool: 5
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

<% environments.each do |environment| %>  

<%= environment %>:
  <<: *defaults
  database: <%= [ database_prefix, current_branch, environment ].join('_') %>
<% end %>
```

### `lib/tasks/db.rake`

Here's a Rake task to easily clone your database from one branch to another. This takes a `SOURCE_BRANCH` and a `TARGET_BRANCH` environment variables. Based off of [@spalladino](https://gist.github.com/spalladino/c8c51f12d1957a8b7de0)'s task.

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Clones database from another branch as specified by `SOURCE_BRANCH` and `TARGET_BRANCH` env params."
  task :clone_from_branch do

    abort "You need to provide a SOURCE_BRANCH to clone from as an environment variable." if ENV['SOURCE_BRANCH'].blank?
    abort "You need to provide a TARGET_BRANCH to clone to as an environment variable."   if ENV['TARGET_BRANCH'].blank?

    database_configuration = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    current_database_name = database_configuration["database"]

    source_db = current_database_name.sub(CURRENT_BRANCH, ENV['SOURCE_BRANCH'])
    target_db = current_database_name.sub(CURRENT_BRANCH, ENV['TARGET_BRANCH'])

    mysql_opts =  "-u #{database_configuration['username']} "
    mysql_opts << "--password=\"#{database_configuration['password']}\" " if database_configuration['password'].presence

    `mysqlshow #{mysql_opts} | grep "#{source_db}"`
    raise "Source database #{source_db} not found" if $?.to_i != 0

    `mysqlshow #{mysql_opts} | grep "#{target_db}"`
    raise "Target database #{target_db} already exists" if $?.to_i == 0

    puts "Creating empty database #{target_db}"
    `mysql #{mysql_opts} -e "CREATE DATABASE #{target_db}"`

    puts "Copying #{source_db} into #{target_db}"
    `mysqldump #{mysql_opts} #{source_db} | mysql #{mysql_opts} #{target_db}`

  end

end
```

### `lib/tasks/git.rake`

This task will create a git branch off of the current branch (master, or otherwise), check it out and clone the current branch's database into the new branch's database. It's slick AF.

```
namespace :git do

  desc "Create a branch off the current branch and clone the current branch's database."
  task :branch do 
    print 'New Branch Name: '
    new_branch_name = STDIN.gets.strip 

    CURRENT_BRANCH = `git status | head -1`.to_s.gsub('On branch ','').chomp

    say "Creating new branch and checking it out..."
    sh "git co -b #{new_branch_name}"

    say "Cloning database from #{CURRENT_BRANCH}..."

    ENV['SOURCE_BRANCH'] = CURRENT_BRANCH # Set source to be the current branch for clone_from_branch task.
    ENV['TARGET_BRANCH'] = new_branch_name
    Rake::Task['db:clone_from_branch'].invoke

    say "All done!"
  end

end
```

Now, all you need to do is run `bundle exec git:branch`, enter in the new branch name and start killing zombies.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should take this as a hint that your development database is too big? If you can use db/seeds.rb and a smaller data set for development then your issue can be easily solved by using schema.rb and seeds.rb from the current branch.

That assumes that your question relates to development; I can't imagine why you'd need to regularly switch branches in production.

Comment: I didn't know about `db/seeds.rb`, I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I have done and I'm not quite sure that I have covered all the bases:

In development (using postgresql):

- sql_dump  db_name > tmp/branch1.sql
- git checkout branch2
- dropdb db_name
- createdb db_name
- psql db_name < tmp/branch2.sql # (from previous branch switch)

This is a lot faster than the rake utilities on a database with about 50K records.

For production, maintain the master branch as sacrosanct and all migrations are checked in, shema.rb properly merged.  Go through your standard upgrade procedure.

Comment: For small enough database sizes and having this done in the background when checking out a branch looks like a very nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same issue.  Here is my solution:

1. Make sure that both schema.rb and all migrations are checked in by all developers.
2. There should be one person/machine for deployments to production.  Let's call this machine as the merge-machine.  When the changes are pulled to the merge machine, the auto-merge for schema.rb will fail.  No issues.  Just replace the content with whatever the previous contents for schema.rb was (you can put a copy aside or get it from github if you use it ...).
3. Here is the important step.  The migrations from all developers will now be available in db/migrate folder.  Go ahead and run bundle exec rake db:migrate.  It will bring the database on the merge machine at par with all changes.  It will also regenerate schema.rb.
4. Commit and push the changes out to all repositories (remotes and individuals, which are remotes too).  You should be done!

Answer (score 2):

You want to preserve a "db environment" per branch. Look at smudge/clean script to point to different instances. If you run out of db instances, have the script spin off a temp instance so when you switch to a new branch, it's already there and just needs to be renamed by the script. DB updates should run just before you execute your tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution is only good for "temporary" branches. For example, if we have a branch "edge" were we test all kinds of crazy stuff (probably with other sub-branches) and then merge it to the master from time to time, the 2 databases will drift apart (their data will not be the same).

Comment: This solution is good for the exact opposite. This is a very good solution if you version your database version script.

Answer (score 2):

I totally experience the pita you are having here. As I think about it, the real issue is that all the branches don't have the code to rollback certain branches. I'm in the django world, so I don't know rake that well. I'm toying with the idea that the migrations live in their own repo that doesn't get branched (git-submodule, which I recently learned about). That way all the branches have all the migrations. The sticky part is making sure each branch is restricted to only the migrations they care about. Doing/keeping track of that manually would be a pita and prone to error. But none of the migration tools are built for this. That is the point at which I am without a way forward.

Comment: This is a nice idea but what happens when a branch renames a column? The rest of the branches will be looking at a broken table.

Comment: um - that is the sticky part - which branch cares about which migrations. so you can go "sync" and it knows, "revert this migration" so the column goes back.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of two options:

#### Option 1

1. Put your data in `seeds.rb`. A nice option is to create your seed data via FactoryGirl/Fabrication gem. This way you can guarantee that the data is in sync with the code if we assume, that the factories are updated together with the addition/removal of columns.
2. After switching from one branch to another, run `rake db:reset`, which effectively drops/creates/seeds the database.

#### Option 2

Manually maintain the states of the database by always running `rake db:rollback`/`rake db:migrate` before/after a branch checkout. The caveat is that all your migrations need to be reversible, otherwise this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a git pull, you should already have the latest schema, affected by any migrations that came in via the pull, but your database tables may not be updated

So, you do need to run the migrations after pulling, but this will often change `db/schema.rb`

If all you've done is pull and migrate, there's no reason you should be responsible for committing any of the resultant schema changes as they don't technically belong to you, and they may end up being extraneous/incorrect

Resetting the schema diff makes the most sense

Here is my step by step version of what to do before creating a new branch

- Switch to your parent/base branch
- Pull the latest code
- Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to update your `schema.rb` file locally
- Do a `git checkout db/schema.rb` to throw away the changes brought by `db:migrate` if any
- Create your new branch and switch to it
- Make sure to commit your changes before switching to another branch

Adapted from [here](https://fuzzyblog.io/blog/rails/2019/05/09/rails-migrations-multiple-developers-and-the-schema-wtf-moment.html)

Answer (score 0):

On development environment:

You should work with `rake db:migrate:redo` to test if your script are reversible, but keep in mind always should have a `seed.rb` with the data population.

If you work with git, you seed.rb should be change with an migration change, and the execution of `db:migrate:redo` for the begining (load the data for a new development on other machine or new database)

Apart of ´change´, with yours up's and down's methods your code always be cover scenarios for the "change" in this moment and when start from zero.