# How do I manage the database/migration when checking out earlier commits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, activerecord, migration

### Scenario description:

I have a master and a feature branch for my source control.

---- master
      \-- feature

I have a column called `useless_column` for my `User` model, which is present in master branch, which i want to drop in feature branch.

Now, I **drop** `useless_column` using rails migrations in **feature branch** removing all code that depends on that column and commit. `schema.rb` and psql database are now updated.

### Question:

Next, suddenly, I realize I made a mistake, and I want to **go back to the master branch** and discontinue working on feature branch. So, I `git checkout -b master`, but at this point I cannot `db:rollback` or `schema:load` or anything because the database **has forgotten all the values** in the `useless_column` which the master branch still depends on.

Does this mean I had to make a dump before I removed this column? If so, then the workflow is to make a database dump everytime you do a migration? If not, then how do you solve this problem?

Related link: [How to work with Git branches and Rails migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735058/how-to-work-with-git-branches-and-rails-migrations)

Useful link: http://technotes.iangreenleaf.com/posts/2013-09-10-rails-migrations-and-schema.html

Comment: Yes, you have to make a database backup before you run migrations that _remove_ or _alter_ data.